# Cannot compile "com.amazonaws.services.batch" classes in eclipse

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am getting compilation errors in eclipse when I want to import com.amazonaws.services.batch classes. 
I have aws-java-sdk-1.11.202 installed. Can someone help?

Comment: Post your error messages. This will help get better responses.

Comment: is it imported successfully ? are you using maven ?

Comment: I have set the classpath of the project to "aws-java-sdk-1.11.202.jar" It works now. Thanks.